# Are attribution sources correctly collected in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

In our android application, we use many great Firebase tools, including analytics.

However, we have a problem because we do not know exactly how it is measured. Our implementation of Firebase Analytics is default.

The following image shows that **organic** source practically does not exist:
[image]
In the case of the mobile site in Google Analytics this traffic is **30% organic** and **70% cpc**.

Why are there such differences? It is not possible that such a disproportion between paid traffic and organic traffic from Google.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with my iOS application.